# Extracting x to y pages from PDF file without parsing the whole file

Tags: java, python, http, pdf, pdfbox

I have a two micro-services: one for taking excerpt and one for serving files such as PDF. I have to get the PDF file from the other micro-service, but having to transfer the whole file over the network is slow. I am trying to find a way to transfer only necessary amount of bytes in order to extract x to y pages of the PDF.

For this I can use HTTP 'Range' header to specify which bytes I need. However, I am having trouble finding a PDF library (can be written in any programming language) which allows me to extract the x to y pages without parsing the whole document (I tried [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html)). I am looking for a library, but ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: unless the pdf in question is linearized, objects used for different pages can be randomly intermixed. Thus, it usually makes no sense to try and use HTTP 'Range'. Regular pdf libraries, therefore, don't even try.

Comment: @mkl I understand. Thanks for response.